# RabbitMQ docker container persistence on Windows

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, erlang, docker-compose

I've created a `docker-compose.yml` file and when trying to **"up"** it, I'm failing to have my `RabbitMQ` docker container persisting to my host volume. It's complaining about the `erlang` cookie file not being accessible by owner only.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

[image]

So I added the above volume binding and rabbitmq seems to be placing files into that directory when I do a `docker-compose up`. I then add 2 messages and I can see via the rabbitmq console that the 2 messages are sitting in the queue...but then when I perform a `docker-compose down` followed by a `docker-compose up`, expecting the 2 messages to still be there as the directory and files were created, but they aren't and the message count=0 :(.

Comment: try using administrator account

Comment: I'm fairly new to docker - how would I do this within a docker-compose file? Or would I need to run the docker-compose command as admin?

Comment: command as admin

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately that hasn't worked :(. Thank you in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's trying to access some privileged user functions.

Try adding `privileged: true` section to your docker-compose service in yml and do `docker-compose up` again.

If it works and you prefer to do some privileges, only what RabbitMQ needs, replace `privileged: true` by capability section for adding or dropping privileges:

```
cap_add:
  - ALL
  - <WHAT_YOU_PREFER>

cap_drop:
  - NET_ADMIN
  - SYS_ADMIN
  - <WHAT_YOU_PREFER>
```

For further information, please check [Compose file documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

**EDIT:**

> In order to provide data persistency when containers fails, add volumes section to docker-compose.yml file
>   `volumes: /your_host_dir_with_data:/destination_in_docker`

Comment: It still didn't work :( but thank you. What I'm trying to do is get RabbitMQ running in docker but on restart, it needs to persist messages prior to the restart. Loosing hair over this...

Comment: Try to put this messages in a `bind volume`. Docker volumes are folders mounted from host to docker when container starts, so, is possible to have data persistency.
Try add volumes: section to your docker-compose file

Comment: Thanks for that. I had tried that too - see my edit. Do you perhaps know what I could be doing wrong? I really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Check that `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia` doesn't exist in container before mounting volume. If directory exist, volume is not mounted properly.
1. Launch your docker without `volume:` section.
2. `docker exec -ti <container_name> bash`
3. `ls /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia`
If exists, use another unexisting folder if you can configure it, for example `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/yourfolder`

Comment: @CraigM I see you marked this as the correct answer, but you also stated this didn't work: what was your final solution/fix?

Comment: Are your queues durable ?  (And your messages as well ?)